# WSL run a non-login shell even with `--shell-type login`

Tags: bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Previously running `wsl` sourced `.profile` for me, as expected:

> [As of build 16188 when running bash.exe without arguments (or with the ~ argument) bash will be launched as a login shell. **The same is true for the new wsl.exe binary (with the exception that wsl launches your user's default shell as a login shell).**](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/816#issuecomment-301216901)

However, recently something changed and I see only `.bashrc` sourced. When searching for information on this problem, I found presence of `.bash_profile` could prevent sourcing `.profile`, and indeed some script I ran recently created a `.bash_profile`. But deleting it didn't help.

Then I found `wsl` seems to launch a non-login shell instead:

```
PS C:\Users\Alexey> wsl
alexey@DESKTOP-41AVESA:/mnt/c/Users/Alexey$ shopt login_shell
login_shell     off
```

The strange thing is that this even happens when run explicitly with `--shell-type login`:

```
PS C:\Users\Alexey> wsl --shell-type login
alexey@DESKTOP-41AVESA:/mnt/c/Users/Alexey$ shopt login_shell
login_shell     off
```

Is there a reason this could happen or should I report a bug to WSL?

```
PS C:\Users\Alexey> wsl --version
WSL version: 2.0.9.0
Kernel version: 5.15.133.1-1
WSLg version: 1.0.59
MSRDC version: 1.2.4677
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.3085
```

`.wslconfig`:

```
[wsl2]
memory=16GB  # Limits VM memory in WSL 2
processors=4 # Makes the WSL 2 VM use this number of virtual processors

[experimental]
autoMemoryReclaim=gradual
sparseVhd=true
```

`/etc/wsl.conf`:

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```